# stat system call reports "No such file or directory"

Tags: c

I'm working on a **homework** assignment and I ran into a little snag.

I'm trying to read a filename from standard input and then `stat` the file to get the size (as per the assignment's requirements):

```
#define BUFFSIZE 4096

int
main(void) {
    int n;

    char buffer[BUFFSIZE];

    struct stat buf;

    while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, BUFFSIZE)) > 0) {
        stat(buffer, &buf);
        perror("stat");
    }
}
```

Here's the output when ran (I entered the filename `file`):

```
file
stat: No such file or directory
```

But if I try something like this:

```
#define BUFFSIZE 4096

int
main(void) {
    int n;

    char buffer[BUFFSIZE] = "file";

    struct stat buf;

    stat(buffer, &buf);
    perror("stat");
}
```

I get:

```
stat: Success
```

The file named `file` is in the directory that I'm running the program from.

How come there is a difference between reading in the string "file" and just initializing the array to the string "file"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before calling `stat()` print the value of `buffer` to standard output:

```
printf("[%s]\n", buffer);
```

It will not be what you expect as `read()` will not NULL terminate `buffer` for you.
Initialise `buffer` before `read()`.

Not sure why you looping on the `read()` as you should acquire the complete name of the file before calling `stat()`. If you have not been forced to use `read()` consider using [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/).

Answer (score 3):

Did you try printing the buffer?  Most likely your `read` call returned a newline on the end of the string "file," and there is no file "file\n" in your directory.  I would recommend using [fgets](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fgets.html) instead to read the filename from the console.  Use standard C input/output when you can, and only delegate to platform-specific code when there is a measurable benefit (e.g. there is no cross-platform `stat` function in the C standard library, and sometimes Unix I/O can measurably improve performance).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but the assignment requires that I use `read` and `stat`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `'\n'` in the buffer in the 1st snippet. Take it out

```
buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `read` leaves the newline in the buffer, so you try to `stat` `"file\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

`read()` may be reading too much (or not enough) on the first loop. Try printing out what it's read just before the `stat()` call:

```
printf("Read %d characters (%s)\n",n,buf);
```

`read()` is probably a bit low level for this task - I'd recommend using [`scanf()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/) instead.

```
while ( scanf ("%s",buffer) == 1) {
```

For safe code, you'll need to specify the maximum number of characters to read, which you can do like this:

```
while ( scanf ("%4096s",buffer) == 1) {
```

However, if you want to use the BUFFSIZE macro, you'll need to do a bit of [mucking about](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification):

```
#define XLIM_PERCENT_S(x) "%" #x "s"
#define LIM_PERCENT_S(x) XLIM_PERCENT_S(x)  

....  

while ( scanf ( LIM_PERCENT_S( BUFFSIZE ) , buffer) == 1) {
```